# emacs M-x dired-toggle-marks 毎回しなければならない？

Tags: emacs

たまにここで質問させてもらい、助かっています。

M-x dired-toggle-marksコマンドでディレクトリー表示が見やすくなります。
しかし、ディレクトリーが変わる毎にこのコマンドを実行する必要があり
面倒です。何か良い方法はありますか？

Comment: `mark` する＝ファイルを `dired` の操作対象にする (`chmod` の対象とかにする) ということなので「見やすくする」機能ではないのです。ちょっと危険すぎてお勧めできないっス。

Comment: 自動で`dired-toggle-marks`を実行することは可能ですがやるべきではないです。本当の目的はファイル名に色を付けることですか?

Comment: 了解です。色変更する事で何とかなりそうなのでその方法でやってみます。